# Will Container installed on UNIX OS use UNIX's Kernel for its UBUNTU base image?

Tags: kubernetes, unix, linux-kernel, operating-system, containers

Suppose we install Docker or any Container platform on UNIX based OS and if we use UBUNTU as BASE OS for application running inside a container by using following line.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
```

Now the question is whether the container will use the host OS's Kernel i.e. ***UNIX KERNEL*** for its operations?

Because it is written that

Docker image/container only has the application layer of the OS and uses the kernel and CPU of the host machine. It is clear from this line that the container will use the host machine's kernel i.e UNIX Kernel in our case.

Comment: Docker doesn't run natively on most Unices, only Linux.

Comment: @DavidMaze as it need lightweight Linux virtual machine (VM) for running docker on top of the Windows host. like that it need LW-VM on UNIX also?

Comment: Docker Desktop for Mac, for example, runs a Linux VM on a Unix OS.  (As for that matter does Docker Desktop for Linux.)